# JQAssistant with multiple projects and builds

Tags: java, maven, neo4j, jqassistant

I have JQAssistant scanning my project(s) and can query each of the projects.  The documentation cites a Team Server ability where all projects/builds are stored in a central Neo4j db.

I cannot find any documentation though on how this would be handled, or what happens for multiple builds.  Nodes do not seem to be tagged with a build number, and neither with the project name, so it appears to be one big lump.

Is there an easy way to tag everything on the way in with projectName and BuildNumber, or am I missing something?  I assume I could tag everything one JQAssistant is run and tag everything missing these tags, but then I lose parallelism and seems too hacky.

This would also help pruning data based on old builds to avoid too much build-up.

Any help much appreciated,

Answer (score 1):

There's a little misunderstanding: the idea behind the team instance is to have Neo4j instance per project with a single (i.e. latest) snapshot of the graph (usually filled by a nightly CI run). So there's currently no build (identifiable by a date, number etc.) in the data - but could be an interesting feature.

Comment: Ok, yeah doesn’t read well at all.  Is the a way I can tag everything jqa puts in though per project easily?

Comment: No, sadly not. I think it could make sense to create "Scan" nodes containing some meta-information (timestamp, project root if available, etc.) which references the root elements that were created during a scan. Would be a new feature though...